# Jhipster Lite Generator

Tags: jhipster

I cloned the jhipster-lite repo to my local pc, built and run it. It is working fine, but I cannot access the http://localhost:7471/generator, it is just showing a blank screen but the swagger and landscape pages are working.

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL is http://localhost:7471/landscape.

Note that you can also start the generator by starting it using Docker: `docker run -p 7471:7471 --rm jhipster/jhipster-lite` or by using the online public instance https://lite.jhipster.tech/